# How to generate thumbnail for PDF file without downloading it in the flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I have to display the PDF thumbnail in my chat section, so i need to generate the corresponding doc thumbnail. I tried different methods, but most methods need to be download the file and pick the corresponding file from the local storage to be generate the image of the doc. Is there any way to solve my issue? if anything exists already then please help me to reach there. Thank you.

Comment: did you later solve this

Comment: Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pdf_render`](https://pub.dev/documentation/pdf_render/latest/#pdf-rendering-apis) APIs to generate a page into a image for thumbnail.

Reference [sample](https://github.com/espresso3389/flutter_pdf_render/issues/48#issuecomment-875369937):

```dart
final pageImage = await page.render();
final image = await pageImage.createImageDetached();
final pngData = await image.toByteData(ImageByteFormat.png);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pdf_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_thumbnail) package.

```
PdfThumbnail.fromFile(pdfFile)
```

disclaimer: It's an open source library that I've developed while ago for my usecases. It's on github and pub.dev.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `pdf_render` and `flutter_cache_manager` packages to show thumbnail image of pdf.

```
Container(
    height: 80.sp,
    width: 80.sp,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.sp),
    color: ColorsCustom.white,
    child: PdfViewer.openFutureFile(
          () async => (await DefaultCacheManager()
                      .getSingleFile(model.fileUrl)).path,
                          viewerController: controller,
                          params: const PdfViewerParams(
                          padding: 0),
            ),
)
```