# How do I show thumbnail of an online pdf

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I'm makeing a firebase server based ebook reader in flutter. but can't find any way to show thumbnail of the books.

I tried to use the thumbnailer and pdf_thumbnail package  but can't find any way there. I was expecting to download and cache the first page as thumbnail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate thumbnail for PDF file without downloading it in the flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69219845/how-to-generate-thumbnail-for-pdf-file-without-downloading-it-in-the-flutter-app)

Answer (score 0):

Use the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview package to render the first page of the PDF as an image, and then display that image as the book thumbnail.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pdfview/flutter_pdfview.dart';

class PdfThumbnail extends StatefulWidget {
  final String path;
  final double height;
  final double width;

  PdfThumbnail({required this.path, required this.height, required this.width});

  @override
  _PdfThumbnailState createState() => _PdfThumbnailState();
}

class _PdfThumbnailState extends State<PdfThumbnail> {
  late PDFViewController pdfViewController;
  Uint8List? imageBytes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _renderPdf();
  }

  void _renderPdf() async {
    final data = await pdfViewController.render(
      page: 1,
      x: 0.0,
      y: 0.0,
      width: widget.width,
      height: widget.height,
    );
    setState(() {
      imageBytes = data!;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return imageBytes != null
        ? Image.memory(
            imageBytes!,
            width: widget.width,
            height: widget.height,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
        : Container();
  }
}
```

then you can use as

```
PdfThumbnail(path: 'Insert_your_path_to_pdf', height: 50, width: 50)
```

I think this will help resolve your problem

Comment: pdfViewController.render() isn't working

Comment: @SiamAhmed could I know the error code.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean by working with online files, but to process them on device, you need to download the file. Once you have the file, you can work with it. Alternatively, consider server side rendering and hosting thumbnails from your server.

I'm the author of the package you've mentioned(pdf_thumbnail), I've used another package called pdfx to render each page as image, one by one. thumbnailer package also depends on pdfx, pdfx does the hard part.

Here's how it works with pdfx:

```
 final document = await PdfDocument.openFile(filePath);
    for (var pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= document.pagesCount; pageNumber++) {
      final page = await document.getPage(pageNumber);
      final pageImage = await page.render(
        width: page.width,
        height: page.height,
      );
      images[pageNumber] = pageImage!.bytes;
      await page.close();
    }
```

In your case, you just need to grab first page. thumbnailer, pdf_thumbnail and pdfx all on pub.dev and github. I suggest refer them if my snippet doesn't solve your problem.